# Jetty HTTP2 server using Headers and Data frames

Tags: java, post, server, jetty, http2

I want to create a Jetty HTTP2 Server that recieves POST requests via stream. 
I noticed that there are more examples about Http2Client then server.

Can anyone help me with some references about http2 server implementation? The technologies that I want to use are Spring 5 and Servlet 4.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This case is invalid, it was an issue on the client part. It is enough to use Servlet 4.x with Spring 5 and jetty (web) server in a java application. According to jetty/http2 documentation, jetty as a server waits the entire request (header and data frames) from the client application and then it will be processed.  In conclusion, there is no additional code on server part.